# I tried enough to solve it, but i can't. Please Help me.The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I'm trying to insert the dates (from & to) in my DB, T try this code, but it always showing me this error:

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

When i remove the middle con.Open(), it throws an exception:

> ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

```
private void btnDiff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Parse(txtFirstDate.Text);
        DateTime fromdate = oldDate;
        DateTime todate = oldDate;

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Topic_ID] FROM [CourseDB].[dbo].[Topic]", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               string column = reader["Topic_ID"].ToString();
               int a = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Topic_ID"]);

               fromdate = todate.AddDays(0);
               todate = fromdate.AddDays(7);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [CourseDB].[dbo].[Topic] SET [From_Date]='" + fromdate.ToString() + "', [To_Date]='" + todate.ToString() + "' WHERE [Topic_ID]='" + a + "'";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Dates Inserted");
                }
                r.Close();
                con.Close();
             }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
     }
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to show how the `con` variable is initialized.

Comment: you have the statement `con.Open();` twice before it ever gets closed.

Comment: I done it Sir using SqlDataAdapter. Thanks.

Comment: You open the connection once in the outer context and close it at the end. But inside your loop, you open&close the connection on each iteration. That won't work

Comment: If you have solved the problem write a answer to your ow question. This way others can benefit.

Comment: #Matt Rowland OK, i'm posting the answer, sorry i was not available from last one week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not understanding what you are doing by below code.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
con.Open();
SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

what command is going to execute by cmd. There is no any command text is specified.

according to me you should make separate connection class, which helps you to maintain the code properly.

```
public class AppConnection
{
    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebConfigConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString; }
    }

    public SqlConnection MakeConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection newConnection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
        if (newConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            newConnection.Open();
        }

        return newConnection;
    }

    public SqlDataReader ExecCommand(string commandText, CommandType commandType, ref SqlConnection appConnection)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader;

        using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand())
        {
            dbCommand.CommandText = commandText;
            dbCommand.CommandType = commandType;
            dbCommand.Connection = appConnection;

            reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }

        return reader;
    }
}
```

and button click event could be like this :-

```
private void btnDiff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Parse(txtFirstDate.Text);
        DateTime fromdate = oldDate;
        DateTime todate = oldDate;

        AppConnection appConnection = new AppConnection();
        SqlConnection con = appConnection.MakeConnection();

        SqlDataReader readerTopics = appConnection.ExecCommand("SELECT [Topic_ID] FROM [CourseDB].[dbo].[Topic]", CommandType.Text, ref con);
        while (readerTopics.Read())
        {
            string column = readerTopics["Topic_ID"].ToString();
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(readerTopics["Topic_ID"]);

            fromdate = todate.AddDays(0);
            todate = fromdate.AddDays(7);

            using (SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand())
            {
                updateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [CourseDB].[dbo].[Topic] SET [From_Date]='" + fromdate.ToString() + "', [To_Date]='" + todate.ToString() + "' WHERE [Topic_ID]='" + a + "'";
                updateCommand.Connection = con;
                updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where would the connection be closed here? I personally don't like returning a Reader object from a method. Its probably better to return some kind of DTO object such as List or DataTable , etc.

Comment: @Emmad Kareem, I have not mentioned here, but connection close method would be define in AppConenction Class and if only loop through to Reader then there would not be require to convert into List or DataTable, as that will also require space in memory. So why should it be convert if there would be no binding to any control.

Comment: My point is that both the reading and the update are part of 1 logical process and they need not be split into more than 1 method. Also, passing parameters directly is to be avoided. Using Arguments is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I just do this, & my problem solved :)

```
DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Parse(txtFirstDate.Text);
            DateTime fromdate = oldDate;
            DateTime todate = oldDate;

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Topic_ID] FROM [CourseDB].[dbo].[Topic]", con);
            con.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string column = row["Topic_ID"].ToString();
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(row["Topic_ID"]);

                fromdate = todate.AddDays(0);
                todate = fromdate.AddDays(7);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [CourseDB].[dbo].[Topic] SET [From_Date]='" + fromdate.ToString() + "', [To_Date]='" + todate.ToString() + "' WHERE [Topic_ID]='" + a + "'";
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                this.topicTableAdapter.Fill(this.courseDataSet.Topic);
```